# Cocoa - Override Lion Window Size Persistency

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, osx-lion

I have a Cocoa App that depends on the main window being a certain size when it opens. While running, however, I drop down a WebView and effectively change the frame size of the window. Next time I open a new window, its the size I left it with the expanded frame size.

I tried resetting the frame size in `-windowWillClose` and in `applicationWillTerminate`, but the former does nothing and the latter crashes the application upon closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck ***Restorable*** (or something like it [I'm not at my Mac right now]) for the window in interface builder. Then make sure the window is shown when your program starts.

Comment: Thanks, its the Restorable check box in the Attributes Inspector. I'll edit accordingly.